# SpringBoot model is not getting displayed on swagger

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, dto

I am using swagger for Documentation but, i see DTO is coming as empty on Swagger UI.

Here's the DTO
[PatientDto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYZkY.png)

and i can see there is empty model in swagger

[Swagger UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xqpj0.png)

Also here the swagger configuration

[Swagger Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vD5sY.png)

Can anyone help.?

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate the controller with:

```
@ApiImplicitParams({
        @ApiImplicitParam(
            name = "patientDto",
            dataType = "PatientDto",
            examples = @io.swagger.annotations.Example(
                value = {
                    @ExampleProperty(value = "’patientDto‘：{'fName': 'John', 'lName='Doe'}", mediaType = "application/json")
                })) 
    })
```

For more information you can see this discussion 
https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2352

it worked for me.